# Azure OAuth Login - Was working, now getting AADSTS700022 / AADSTS700023 Errors

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, office365api

We've had office 365 login for our website working for a couple of months and all of a sudden, its broken.

As of this morning (UK time) we started getting *"AADSTS700023: The provided value for the input parameter scope cannot be empty when requesting an access token using the provided authorization code. Please specify a valid scope."* errors when we request a token via https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Looking at the docs it appears that scope is required and it wasn't being passed, so regardless of the fact its worked for months, I added it. Now I get a different error..

*AADSTS700022: The provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. The scope https://outlook.office.com/mail.send mail.readwrite calendars.readwrite tasks.readwrite contacts.readwrite openid profile offline_access is not valid.*

When we call into the authorise endpoint first of all, this is the scope that gets passed and it comes back fine from that call, however when we try and get the token it fails.

Is there a general Login issue with 365 at the moment or is there something that I'm doing wrong and Microsoft have decided to 'fix' their end?

Answer (score 5):

> > AADSTS700023: The provided value for the input parameter scope cannot be empty when requesting an access token using the provided authorization code. Please specify a valid scope.

When acquiring token to access resource in Azure AD V2.0 , you need to specific `scope` parameter which indicates which resource and permissions the app is requesting authorization for . Please refer to [how OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) in Azure AD v2.0 .

> > AADSTS700022: The provided value for the input parameter scope is not valid because it contains more than one resource. The scope https://outlook.office.com/mail.send mail.readwrite calendars.readwrite tasks.readwrite contacts.readwrite openid profile offline_access is not valid.

An access token issued from Azure AD only available for one resource , you can't use same token to access multi resources . That means you should specific one resource's scopes in your token request . Looking into your scopes :

- `https://outlook.office.com/mail.send` is the scope of Office 365 Unified Mail API
- `mail.readwrite calendars.readwrite tasks.readwrite contacts.readwrite` are the scopes of Microsoft Graph API .

You can't acquire an access token to access two resources .You can request `Mail.Send` scope to send mail using Microsoft Graph API instead of using scope of O365 mail rest api .

Comment: But why has this been working for months and suddenly stopped working? We need to access both APIs as sending email through Graph has a sever limit on the size of attachments that can be sent and we need access to the Graph API for handling incoming mail. Also, I repeat, this is at the Token Stage, we've already passed the authorisation step successfully, with that combined scope

Comment: *penny drops* Ah, does this mean that we can use the combined scope for the authorisation stage, but need to get multiple tokens now for each scope? Instead of sending one token request, we send two, one for the Office 365 Mail API (i.e. https://outlook.office.com/mail.send) and another token request for the Graph API (mail.readwrite calendars.readwrite tasks.readwrite contacts.readwrite)? We'd then store both tokens and use them as appropriate when calling into either the Graph or Office 365 APIs? The user wouldn't have to give permission twice, I presume, because the auth scope covered both?

Comment: Exactly right Steve. So in the past, you were sending `scope=https://outlook.office.com/mail.send mail.readwrite calendars.readwrite tasks.readwrite contacts.readwrite openid profile offline_access` to the authorize endpoint, and no scope parameter to the token endpoint? And you were receiving back a valid access token? Which APIs did you call with this access token?

Comment: @dstrockis - that's exactly right. We're currently only using the Outlook send mail api call, in development we're using the Graph API to monitor the inbox for emails. However the live system broke and all that was doing was requesting the scope above and then getting a token with no scope. As I said, this has been working for probably 2-3 months!

Comment: @NanYu - Microsoft appear to have changed something again! We made the changes above and all was well, but now it appears they've stopped you using an authorisation code twice, which we were doing, after the user had logged into office, we used it get a token for the outlook APi and reused the same code to get a token for the Graph API. In the Auth request, both APIs are specified in the same scope and that Auth bit works fine.

How are you supposed to get the 2nd token when using the auth code to get the first one then invalidates the code? Error code shown in next comment...

Comment: @NanYu - This is the error I get: invalid_grant:AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS54005: OAuth2 Authorization code was already redeemed, please retry with a new valid code or use an existing refresh token.

Comment: Solved it in end, my hypothesis was correct. Use the code to get the token for the graph API (or outlook, but I went with graph first), then use the refresh token value from that to get a token for the Outlook API.

Comment: `The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope mail.readwrite is not valid.`

`The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://outlook.office.com/mail.readwrite is not valid.`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this is as Nan Yu alluded to, for some reason the call had been working for the past couple of months, but you now can't get a token to cover multiple resources (i.e. Graph and Outlook APIs). The solution is to request authentication for a combined scope of both APIs and once you've got that, request separate tokens for the Graph and Outlook APIs.

We've done that and are storing the tokens separately and then when an API Call is made, detecting which API is being used and passing the appropriate token with the API Call.